# Convert GPS coordinate to ArcGIS x,y point?

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, ios, arcgis-runtime-sdk-ios

I'm trying to plot some `AGSSimpleMarkerSymbol's` in a `AGSGraphicsLayer`. The issue I'm running into is that the data I'm starting with are GPS coordinates (lat/lon). I'm using `AGSPoint` to plot the data, however, `AGSPoint` wants x and y points - not lat/lon.

My question is, how do I convert my GPS coordinates to x and y points?

Comment: D'oh... I had the lat/lon reversed in the x and y. My code is now: `[AGSPoint pointWithX:[lon doubleValue] y:[lat doubleValue] spatialReference:self.mapView.spatialReference];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you want to use the `projectGeometry` method from the [AGSGeometryEngine](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-ios-sdk/apiref/interface_a_g_s_geometry_engine.html) class to convert from the GPS coordinate system to the coordinate system used by your map.  Use the `defaultGeometryEngine` for this.

Assuming your GPS is giving you WGS-84 coordinates you could do something like this:

```
CLLocation* gpsLocation = ....

// create a AGSPoint from the GPS coordinates
AGSPoint* gpsPoint = [[AGSPoint alloc] initWithX:gpsLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                               y:gpsLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                spatialReference:[AGSSpatialReference wgs84SpatialReference]];

AGSGeometryEngine* engine = [AGSGeometryEngine defaultGeometryEngine];

// convert GPS WGS-84 coordinates to the map's spatial reference
// (assuming self.mapView is your AGSMapView for your map)
AGSPoint* mapPoint = (AGSPoint*) [engine projectGeometry:gpsPoint 
                                      toSpatialReference:self.mapView.spatialReference];
```

Comment: The full list of supported coordinate systems can be found here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/coordinate-systems/mobilegcs.html

Comment: I am using ArcGIS iOS SDK in my app, I want to track the GPS path. I read the location updates from locationManager API from Apple which returns a lat * long. Can I assume that its spatial reference wgs84SpatialReference. In simple words I have used your code above & how can I confirm if the conversion took place as desired? Plz help

Comment: No need to assume, Apple [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CLLocationCoordinate2D) that `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is in WGS-84 frame of reference.

Answer (score 0):

The two numerals before the decimal point and those after are minutes, the two/three numerals at the front are degrees, i.e. 32 degrees, 46.4270 minutes, 117 degrees, 04.3785 minutes, etc. You can convert these to decimal degrees after loading doesn't need three lines but hopefully this makes the process clearer

Comment: I'd guess the original poster has already solved his problem.